# HTML Table drop down filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I get both filters to work at the same time?  When I select anything in Term it does not work, also if I select All in Gender it does not work.  If I remove one of the filters completely, it is working fine but I can't seem to get both to work simultaneously.  I am guessing it has to do with the function filterText(), do I need to create another one or can it be called more than once?  Any help will be appreciated!

Thank you

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function filterText()
    {  
        var val = $('#filterText').val();
        if(val === "")
           return;
        if(val === "all")
          clearFilter();
        else

        $('.gender').each(function() {
          $(this).parent().toggle($(this).text()=== val);
        });

    }
   function clearFilter()
    {
        $('.filterText').val('');
        $('.row').show();
    }
</script>

<script>
function filterTextTerm()
    {  
        var val = $('#filterTextTerm').val();
        if(val === "")
           return;
        if(val === "all")
          clearFilterTerm();
        else

        $('.term').each(function() {
          $(this).parent().toggle($(this).text()=== val);
        });

    }
   function clearFilterTerm()
    {
        $('.filterTextTerm').val('');
        $('.row').show();
    }
</script>

<table id ="myTable" class="table table-striped">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th> First Name </th>
                    <th> Last Name </th>                  
                    <th> Age 
                      <!--  <select id="filterText"  onchange='filterText()'>
                              <option disabled selected>Select</option>
                              <option value="all">All</option>
                              <option value="15">15</option> 
                              <option value="16">16</option>
                        </select> --></th>
                    <th> Email </th>              
                    <th> Gender
                    <select id="filterText"  onchange='filterText()'>
                              <option disabled selected>Select</option>
                              <option value="all">All</option>
                              <option value="Male">Male</option> 
                              <option value="Female">Female</option>
                        </select></th>
                    <th>Term
                    <select id="filterTextTerm"  onchange='filterTextTerm()'>
                              <option disabled selected>Select</option>
                              <option value="all">All</option>
                              <option value="Fall2018">Fall2018</option> 
                              <option value="Spring2019">Spring2019</option>
                        </select></th>
                        <th> Enrolled </th>


                </tr>
            </thead> 
            <tbody>             
            <tr class='row'>

            <td>John</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td class="age">15</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td class="gender">Male</td>
            <td class="term">Summer2017</td> 
            <td class="enrolled"> Fall2018</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class='row'>

            <td>Jane</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td class="age">16</td>
            <td>456</td>
            <td class="gender">Female</td>
            <td class="term">Fall2018</td> 
            <td class="enrolled"> Fall2019</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class='row'>

            <td>Bobby</td>
            <td>Adams</td>
            <td class="age">15</td>
            <td>789</td>
            <td class="gender">Male</td>
            <td class="term">Spring2019</td>
            <td class="enrolled"> Fall2018</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class='row'>

            <td>Sarah</td>
            <td>Lee</td>
            <td class="age">15</td>
            <td>456</td>
            <td class="gender">Female</td>
            <td class="term">Fall2018</td>
            <td class="enrolled"> Fall2018</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class='row'>

            </tbody> 
        </table>
```

[image]

[image]

Filtering here is not working correctly.

Comment: Your filters share the same id, the id's should be unique.

Comment: I made the changes, is the best way to do that by creating a separate filterText function for each?  Each one now filters, but how do I get both filters to work at the same time?  For example: Male and Fall2018 should show no results, but it shows Female 2018?

Comment: @williswin I inverted the row toggle logic to use `every` instead of `some`, please see the difference below. I used De Morgan's law to invert the if-conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a jQuery plugin that can be re-used. It will both create the filter drop-downs, in place of the header text, and have the ability to filter dynamically.

All you need to do is:

- Set the `class` and `data-field-name` attributes on each `th`.

  - The dropdowns will be populated by the existing values in the table.
  - Filtering by a particular column will look-up the field name in the internal data object and check the class of the cell in the current column index.
- Avoid using a class attribute on the table cells i.e. `td` elements because you can have multiple classes and it will become a tedious check. Use a data attribute instead.

**Note:** The `data-field-name` attribute is OPTIONAL on the `th`, and will infer the field name from the column, as long as that it corresponds. But if you want a row to be filterable, make sure the `td` has the attribute.

---

**Update:** I inverted the row toggle function to use an `every` check instead of a `some` check for the table cell text matching.

```js
$table.find('tbody tr').each(function() {
  $(this).toggle($(this).find('td').toArray().every(td => {
    let $td = $(td), fieldName = $td.attr('data-field-name');
    if (fieldName != null) {
      return filterObj[fieldName] === null ||
        filterObj[fieldName] === '' ||
        filterObj[fieldName] === 'all' ||
        filterObj[fieldName] === $td.text();
    }
    return true;
  }));
});
```

Instead of this:

```js
$table.find('tbody tr').each(function() {
  $(this).toggle(!$(this).find('td').toArray().some(td => {
    let $td = $(td), fieldName = $td.attr('data-field-name');
    if (fieldName != null) {
      return filterObj[fieldName] != null &&
        filterObj[fieldName] != '' &&
        filterObj[fieldName] != 'all' &&
        filterObj[fieldName] != $td.text();
    }
    return false;
  }));
});
```

### Demo

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.tableFilterHeaders = function(filterFn) {
    this.each((index, header) => {
      let $header = $(header),
          $table = $header.closest('table'),
          text = $header.text(),
          colIndex = $header.closest('th').index(),
          fieldName = $header.attr('data-field-name') || text.toLowerCase(),
      $select = $('<select>')
        .data('fieldName', fieldName)
        .append($('<option>').text(text).val('').prop('disabled', true))
        .append($('<option>').text('All').val('all'))
        .append($table.find('tbody tr')
          .toArray()
          .map(tr => {
            return $(tr).find(`td:eq(${colIndex})`).text();
          })
          .filter(text => text.trim().length > 0)
          .sort()
          .filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i)
          .map(text => {
            return $('<option>').text(text).val(text);
          }));
      $header.empty().append($select.val('').on('change', filterFn));
    });
  };
  $.fn.initRowClasses = function(oddCls, evenCls) {
    this.find('tbody tr').each(function(i) {
      $(this).toggleClass(oddCls, i % 2 == 0).toggleClass(evenCls, i % 2 == 1);
    });
  };
  $.fn.updateRowClasses = function(oddCls, evenCls) {
    this.find('tbody tr:visible:even').addClass(oddCls).removeClass(evenCls);
    this.find('tbody tr:visible:odd').addClass(evenCls).removeClass(oddCls);
  };
})(jQuery);

$('#myTable').initRowClasses('odd', 'even');
$('.dropdown-header').tableFilterHeaders(filterText);

function filterText(e) {
  let $filter = $(e.target),
      $table = $filter.closest('table'),
      $filters = $table.find('.dropdown-header select'),
  filterObj = $filters.toArray().reduce((obj, filter) => {
    let $filter = $(filter);
    return Object.assign(obj, { [$filter.data('fieldName')] : $filter.val() });
  }, {});
  if ($filter.val() === 'all') {
    $filter.val('')
  }
  $table.find('tbody tr').each(function() {
    $(this).toggle($(this).find('td').toArray().every(td => {
      let $td = $(td), fieldName = $td.attr('data-field-name');
      if (fieldName != null) {
        return filterObj[fieldName] === null ||
          filterObj[fieldName] === '' ||
          filterObj[fieldName] === 'all' ||
          filterObj[fieldName] === $td.text();
      }
      return true;
    }));
  });

  $table.updateRowClasses('odd', 'even');
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, th, td {
  border: thin solid grey;
}
th, td {
  padding: 0.25em;
}
thead tr {
  background: #DDD;
}
tbody tr.even {
  background: #EEE;
}
tbody tr.odd {
  background: #FFF;
}
th.dropdown-header > select {
  background: inherit;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
th.dropdown-header > select:focus {
  outline: none;
}
table > thead th,
table > thead th > select {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th class="dropdown-header" data-field-name="age">Age</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th class="dropdown-header">Gender</th>
      <th class="dropdown-header">Term</th>
      <th class="dropdown-header">Enrolled</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td data-field-name="age">15</td>
      <td>123</td>
      <td data-field-name="gender">Male</td>
      <td data-field-name="term">Summer2017</td>
      <td data-field-name="enrolled">Fall2018</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>Jane</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td data-field-name="age">16</td>
      <td>456</td>
      <td data-field-name="gender">Female</td>
      <td data-field-name="term">Fall2018</td>
      <td data-field-name="enrolled">Fall2019</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>Bobby</td>
      <td>Adams</td>
      <td data-field-name="age">15</td>
      <td>789</td>
      <td data-field-name="gender">Male</td>
      <td data-field-name="term">Spring2019</td>
      <td data-field-name="enrolled">Fall2018</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>Sarah</td>
      <td>Lee</td>
      <td data-field-name="age">15</td>
      <td>456</td>
      <td data-field-name="gender">Female</td>
      <td data-field-name="term">Fall2018</td>
      <td data-field-name="enrolled">Fall2018</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution!  If I were to have  row.append($("<td>" + rowData.term + "</td>")); to generate the rows based off of a Mysql table, how would i apply data-field-name="term" into that?

Comment: @williswin: Well, you are accessing `rowData.term`, so just put it in manually: `row.append($('<td data-field-name="term">' + rowData.term + '</td>'));`

Comment: it doesn't seem to like the syntax on that

Comment: @williswin: Updated, use single-quotes around the entire string concatenated values, since the class attribute value is wrapped in double-quotes... Or you can try: `row.append($('<td>').attr('data-field-name', 'term').text(rowData.term));`

Comment: That fixed the syntax error, it isn't generating the selection though.  If you can take a look at my new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60381903/html-table-filtering-reading-data-from-mysql
thanks!

Comment: @williswin You need to create the select boxes AFTER the data is there.

Comment: I am able to get the table to generate, just currently not the selections.  Thanks for your comments, I will look into it more.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few problems here.  First, you're missing some curley brackets for some of your conditional `if` `else` statements.  Second, as mentioned in the comments, you cannot have multiple identical `id`'s.  Third, your `$('.gender').each()` loop was overriding anything accomplished in the `$('.term').each()` loop, causing the Term select not to work at all.

Here is a working solution with some modifications to the code you posted: ("Run code snippet")

```js
function filterText(id)  {  // I added an id parameter so we know which select we are filtering
    var val = $(id).val();
    if(val === "")
        return;
    if(val === "all") {
        clearFilter(id);
    } else {   // was missing these if/else curley brackets
        if (id === '#Term') {  // if "#Term", filter term values
            $('.term').each(function() {
                $(this).parent().toggle($(this).text()=== val);
            });
        }
        if (id === '#Gender') { // if "#Gender", filter gender values
            $('.gender').each(function() {
                $(this).parent().toggle($(this).text()=== val);
            }); 
        }       
    }
}
function clearFilter(id) {
    $(id).val('');
    $('.row').show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id ="myTable" class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th> First Name </th>
              <th> Last Name </th>                  
              <th> Age 
                <!--  <select id="filterText"  onchange='filterText()'>
                        <option disabled selected>Select</option>
                        <option value="all">All</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option> 
                        <option value="16">16</option>
                  </select> --></th>
              <th> Email </th>              
              <th> Gender
              <select id="Gender"  onchange='filterText("#Gender")'>
                        <option disabled selected>Select</option>
                        <option value="all">All</option>
                        <option value="Male">Male</option> 
                        <option value="Female">Female</option>
                  </select></th>
              <th>Term
              <select id="Term"  onchange='filterText("#Term")'>
                        <option disabled selected>Select</option>
                        <option value="all">All</option>
                        <option value="Fall2018">Fall2018</option> 
                        <option value="Spring2019">Spring2019</option>
                  </select></th>
                  <th> Enrolled </th>


          </tr>
      </thead> 
      <tbody>             
      <tr class='row'>

      <td>John</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td class="age">15</td>
      <td>123</td>
      <td class="gender">Male</td>
      <td class="term">Summer2017</td> 
      <td class="enrolled"> Fall2018</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class='row'>

      <td>Jane</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td class="age">16</td>
      <td>456</td>
      <td class="gender">Female</td>
      <td class="term">Fall2018</td> 
      <td class="enrolled"> Fall2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class='row'>

      <td>Bobby</td>
      <td>Adams</td>
      <td class="age">15</td>
      <td>789</td>
      <td class="gender">Male</td>
      <td class="term">Spring2019</td>
      <td class="enrolled"> Fall2018</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class='row'>

      <td>Sarah</td>
      <td>Lee</td>
      <td class="age">15</td>
      <td>456</td>
      <td class="gender">Female</td>
      <td class="term">Fall2018</td>
      <td class="enrolled"> Fall2018</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class='row'>

      </tbody> 
  </table>
```

**Note:** If you want to filter by Gender, Term (and Age, and other columns) simultaneously, I think you're going to need to re-factor your logic alltogether.. You'll need to loop through all the table rows and filter(toggle) each column based on All the values that are currently selected in All the select boxes. It would be a different approach where you would probably just want to start over.

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I needed?  If I wanted to add a filter for age, is it the same concept for integers vs texts?

Comment: @williswin, yes totally, but you would just treat the integers as strings, just exactly like the other ones (gender & term). Awesome, good luck! :)

Comment: Bryan, I was looking to do something like you mentioned in the Note.  Filter with Gender, Term, Age, plus whatever needed.  Can I go ahead and post another question, I will link it here.

Comment: Yes, posting another question would be the correct way to do it.  Yes if you post the link here, I'll jump over and see if I can help!  :)  thanks

Comment: @williswin, However, you may want to take a look at this solution before you post a new question.  It may solve your problem, maybe.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45990106/filter-table-with-three-select-inputs-using-jquery

Comment: Thanks for that link!  I added a few other criteria I was hoping to get accomplished so I went ahead and created a new question.  If you can assist, thanks
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60327431/multiple-drop-down-filters-for-html-table

Comment: I noticed if you use this approach and select "Female" and "Spring2019" the only row that is shown is a Male row - not sure this is what OP wanted since they asked "for both filters to work at the same time" so I am confused why they seem to accept this.

Comment: @AndrewLohr Check my response below, I implemented multi-field filtering.